# How to delete AWS Secrets under Secret Manager using AWS CLI which are not retrieved in last 6 months

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

We create many secrets in AWS secret manager. I need help to know how can i delete  all the AWS Secrets (under secret manager) which are not used /retrieved in last 60 days in bulk. I tried to find a AWS CLI command to do so but nothing really worked.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`list_secrets()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.list_secrets) returns:

```json
{
    'SecretList': [
        {
            'ARN': 'string',
            'Name': 'string',
            'Description': 'string',
            'KmsKeyId': 'string',
            'RotationEnabled': True|False,
            'RotationLambdaARN': 'string',
            'RotationRules': {
                'AutomaticallyAfterDays': 123
            },
            'LastRotatedDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'LastChangedDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'LastAccessedDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'DeletedDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            ...
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

The `LastAccessedDate` looks like it will be useful for you. You can use it with the AWS CLI like this:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets --query 'SecretList[?LastAccessedDate<`2021-06-01`].ARN'
```

If you are good at writing shell scripts, you could write a script then deletes the secrets that are returned. Otherwise, I'd recommend doing it in a programming language (eg Python) since it can be a bit easier than Shell Script.